# How to return Map in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

***How to get apiRequest method return value?***

**This function create outside**

```
 Future<Map> apiRequest(String url, Map jsonMap) async {
      HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient();
      HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
      request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
      HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
      print(response);
      print(request);
      // todo - you should check the response.statusCode

      String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      Map valueMap = json.decode(reply);
      print(valueMap);
      httpClient.close();
      return valueMap;
    }
```

**inside the main function, I pass the values**

```
var value = apiRequest(url, {"username":"admin"});
```

**But i can't pass this value to my model class**

```
UsernameModel model = UsernameModel.fromJson(value);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? This looks like a type issue but it's a bit hard to tell for sure without an error message.

Comment: can you put json here, which is 'reply'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `async`/`await` in `main` as well. Async execution is contagious and you can't go back from an async call to non-async execution.

```
Future main() async {
  var value = await apiRequest(url, {"username":"admin"});
  UsernameModel model = UsernameModel.fromJson(value);
  ...
}
```